# Edit CSS template doesn't take effect

Tags: css, ftp

I edited the an order form for a friend of mine (http://www.christinat-vin.ch/commande).

Unfortunately, the footer is hiding a bit the last field, and I can't fix it. I've tried to change the margin by editing the css file through the FTP, but it doesn't take effect.

Am I missing something ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. After changing the css, clear the browser cache and reload, does that help?

Comment: Yes, indeed ! But I don't understand why the footer is still hidding the content of the PHP form...do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? That is, strip the source down to the absolute minimum required to show the problem. In the process, you could be able to discover what the culprit is; if not, post the example here in the question.